# SQL INSTR() using CSV. Need exact match rather than part

Tags: sql

This is a follow up issue relating to the answer for [SQL placeholder in WHERE IN issue, inserted strings fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445029/sql-placeholder-in-where-in-issue-inserted-strings-fail)

Quick background: We have a SQL query that uses a placeholder value to accept a string, which represents a unique tag/id. Usually, this is only a single tag, but we needed the ability to use a csv string for multiple tags, returning a combined result.

In the answer we received from the vendor, they suggested the use of the `INSTR` function, ala:

```
select *  
from pitotal  
where tag IN (SELECT tag from pipoint WHERE INSTR(?, tag) <> 0) and time between 'y' and 't'
```

This works perfectly well 99% of the time, the issue is when the `tag` is also a subset of 2 parts of the CSV string. Eg the placeholder value is: `'northdom,southdom,eastdom,westdom'`

and possible tags include:
`north` or `northdom`

What happens, as `north` is a subset of `northdom`, is that the two tags are return instead of just `northdom`, which is actually what we want.

I'm not strong on SQL so I couldn't work out how to set it as exact, or split the csv string, so help would be appreciated.

Is there a way to split the csv string or make it look for an exact match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a query like this it should work. Given that you surround the tag with commas.

```
select *  
from pitotal  
where tag IN (SELECT tag from pipoint WHERE INSTR(?, ',' || tag || ',') <> 0) and time between 'y' and 't'
```

Basically... instead of searching for `north` we'll be searching for `,north,`. And instead of searching in `northdom,southdom,eastdom,westdom` we'll search in  `,northdom,southdom,eastdom,westdom,`

Comment: +1, We ended up using a slight variation on this, mainly because our SQL didn't support the || operator (for some reason). We ended up using `INSTR(',' + ? + ',' , ',' + tag + ',')` which seems to work exactly as planned. Thanks!